# Getting text to change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Very new to Javascript.

Trying to get the text "Paragraph changed" to change to "New" when button is clicked. Not too sure why this is happening.

Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My First Web Page</h1>
<p id="demo">My first paragraph.</p>

<script>
function firstFunction(){
    document.getElementByID("demo").innerHTML="New";
</script>

<button type="button" onclick="firstFunction()">Try it</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: include your script before closing of body tag.

Comment: I have, please see edit

Comment: no, you didn't. include after button.

Comment: The location of the script doesn't matter, it can be before, after, or within the `body`, it will still work.

Answer (score 3):

There are two issues I can spot immediately:

1. You do not have a closing curly brace in your function
2. The `getElementById` function is misspelled, the last letter should not be capitalized.

You would see both issues in the browser console as you load the page. It is often displayed if you press `ctrl+shift+I`, `Ctrl+shift+J` or `F12`, or search for it in the tools menu. When you open it, go to `console` tab and you will see the errors that occur.

Here's more details on how to open the console:

https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers

Answer (score 0):

Your script position doesn't matter, though it is best to place it just before you close the body tag for loading issues.

Your issue is two fold.  First make sure that when declaring a function you close your curly braces.  Second the function name is `getElementById` not `getElementByID`  JavaScript is case sensitive.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <h1>My First Web Page</h1>
  <p id="demo">My first paragraph.</p>

  <script>
    function firstFunction() {
      <!-- Id is not capitalized -->
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "New";
    } <!-- important curly brace -->
  </script>

  <button type="button" onclick="firstFunction()">Try it</button>

</body>

</html>
```